# pass parameter from controller to view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, smarty

I am passing

```
$router->map('Owner', 'Owner/:is_owner','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'index','is_owner'=>'1'));
```

$router->map('Client', 'Client/:is_owner','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'index','is_owner'=>'0'));

in controller I'm getting it by,

```
 $flag=$_GET['is_owner'];
```

in view I want to access $flag...how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using smarty you could do it as:

```
//In controller
$smarty->assign('flag',  $flag);

//In view
{$flag}
```